# Array Equivalent of Bare-String

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initializer-list, bare

I can do this without issue:

```
const char* foo = "This is a bare-string";
```

What I want is to be able to do the same thing with an array:

```
const int* bar = {1, 2, 3};
```

Obviously that code doesn't compile, but is there some kind of array equivalent to the bare-string?

Comment: `const int bar[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Right that obviously works. What I'm asking is how is `"This"` different from `{'T', 'h', 'i', 's'}`? And is there a `"This"` equivalent for numeric arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
const int* bar = {1, 2, 3};
```

But you can do this:

```
const int bar[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Reason is that char* in C (or C++) have an added functionality, besides working as a char pointer, it also works as a "C string", thus the added initialization method (special for char*):

```
const char* foo = "This is bare-string";
```

Best.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate? Is a "C String" some kind of hidden special object? Note that you can't do this in C++ either: `const char* foo = {'T', 'h', 'i', 's'};`

Comment: C string is the same as char*, it's not a hidden special object.
C string is what you get when you call .c_str() from a std::string.
The only difference is that char* (or C string) have a this special initialization, you can't find an analogous version of this initialization in int* for instance.

It's like doing:
`char foo[] = {'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
char* bar = &foo;`

In a single, more readable way:
`char* bar = "String";`

Comment: Maybe the equivalent version would be something like:
`int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};
int* bar = &foo;`

But then you don't have the "abbreviated" version:
`int* bar = "123"; O.O`

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is, there isn't a way to do this, I'd have to use `int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};`